# Array returning the sum of calculations

Tags: java, arrays

I have to finish this method that returns the sum of the CDD calculations over a whole month. My cdd method that I use to calculate the sum  is below first. Can I get a hint as to how to go about this? I struggle with arrays and I'm unsure of how to start.

```
public static double cdd(int max, int min)
{
    double average = ((max + min) / 2.0);
    double cdd = 0.0;

    if (average > 65.0)
    {
        cdd = average - 65.0;
    }
    else
    {
        cdd = 0.0;
    }

    if (max == -999 || min == -999)
    {
        cdd = 0.0;
    }
    else if (max < min)
    {
        cdd = 0.0;   
    }

    return cdd;


public static double monthCdd(int[] max, int[] min)
{
    double sum = 0.0;

    max = new int[31];
    min = new int[31];
    cdd(,);


    return sum;        
}
```

Comment: Where does your data come from? I mean: your arrays `max` and `min` both have data elements in them, so where does this data come from? Do **you** make it up? Or what?

Answer (score 1):

After populating the `max` and `min`arrays,

1. Start a `for` loop which will run from 0 to `max.length - 1` with the counter variable `i`.
2. Call the `cdd()` method in loop by passing the current index element from each of the arrays, something like this, `cdd(max[i], min[i])`.
3. Keep adding the value returned from `cdd()` method to the `sum` variable, `sum += cdd(max[i], min[i]);`

Answer (score 0):

You might want to do something like this:

```
final int length= 31;
double sum=0.0
max =new int[length];
min= new int[length];
//add code to initialize the arrays
for(int i=0;i<length;i++) {
  sum +=cdd(min[i],max[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you struggle with arrays, then the first thing I'd suggest is playing around with iterators in Java.

In pseudo, the method should perform elementary operations on each index of two arrays. Accessing the content of *both* arrays will require an iterator that "steps" through each index of the array, beginning with 0 and ending with the last index (hence why others have suggested declaring a static length).

The statement:

```
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
```

simply states "for every (arbitrary variable) **i** on the interval [0, length), perform some action using **i**, then increment **i** by one for the next loop"

Understand this, and you have the means to add each index of two arrays (same size), i.e.

```
sum += arr1[i] + arr2[i]
```